# Can't skip to next song on Spotify API (via Spotipy)

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm implementing a simple application with `spotipy`.
I want to skip the next track, but I've got this error in output:

> spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next:
>   Not available for the current user

My code:

```
import os
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError


# Set data client, redirect URL and username
username = 'xxxx'
client_id = 'xxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxx'
redirect_uri = 'https://www.xxxxx.it/'
scope = 'user-modify-playback-state'


# Erase cache and prompt for user permission
try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
except (AttributeError, JSONDecodeError):
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)


# Configure Spotify
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
current = sp.next_track()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip songs only for premium users.
Check these articles:

- [Skip User’s Playback To Next Track](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/skip-users-playback-to-next-track/)
- [Using the Spotify Connect Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/using-connect-web-api/)

FYI, **[Error 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)** is authorization error:

> The HTTP **`403 Forbidden`** client error status response code indicates
>   that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [`401`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating
>   will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied
>   to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlessandroMinervini Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)